# Is there a trick to do background tasks with react native expo?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

I know expo cannot execute code when the app is in the background but i really need to find a alternative. I need to update my redux state when i receive a push notification in the background.

Is there any additional library to help me to do such things ?

Answer (score 3):

As of Apr 2019, Expo does allow some background tasks to be done, using their [TaskManager](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/task-manager/). Two examples of built-in backgrounds task are:

- Background geolocation (including geofencing): [see docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/location/#locationstartlocationupdatesasynctaskname-options).
- Background fetch: [see docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/background-fetch/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not possible in react native.

You can "eject" your app with `npm run eject`(**There is NO go back**). And add native code with java for android AND with swift for iOS to handle background tasks.